# How to move a submenu and all items under it to another parent menu in Ektron?

Tags: ektron

I use the menu tab under content. My current menu structure is as below

```
   MainMenu 
     Sub menu Level 2
        Submenu level 3 (1)
          item 1
          item 2 
          item 3
        Submenu level 3 (2)
          item 41
          item 5 
          item 6
```

What I want is as below

```
   MainMenu 
    Submenu Level 1
     Sub menu Level 2
        Submenu level 3 (1)
          item 1
          item 2 
          item 3
        Submenu level 3 (2)
          item 41
          item 5 
          item 6
```

Please note that I want to add a new submenu under MainMenu and want the previously added submenu and every thing under it to come under the new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not appear to be a way to do this through the UI interface, but it is relatively simple to do via the database.

There are two key tables for menus: `menu_tbl` and `menu_to_item_tbl`.

In the `menu_tbl`, find the row for the item you'd like to move. Note the `mnu_id` for that item. You'll probably want to export the whole `menu_tbl` as an excel, and refer back later as you make changes.

To move a specific menu item to another place, note that the menu item has a parent_id of the item it belongs to, and the ID of the item you want to move (it shows up in the Ektron admin).

Then you can take these steps:

1. If the item is a menu folder itself, you need to change this parent_id to point to the new parent's `mnu_id` in the `menu_tbl` table.
2. Then open the `menu_to_item_tbl` up and change the query to query the `mnu_id` of the parent by adding a "where mnu_id = ". The results should show the subitems for the parent, including the item you want to move. Change the `mnu_id` of the item to match the parent `mnu_id` as well.